# Pandas read_csv dtype and chunk is inconsistent

Tags: python, pandas, aws-glue

When reading a somewhat large csv (around 300,000 rows by 160 columns), declaring dtype via dictionary provides inconsistent results.  Data are localized to European standards so I've declared the decimal and thousands separator as well.

When setting chunksize to 25000, pandas reads the first 49,999 records and datatypes the columns as expected.  On the 50,000th record, however, pandas throws a valueError stating it cannot convert string '0,00' to float. Interestingly, after the chunk that contains the 50,000th record, subsequent chunks are properly datatyped.

Not sure if it matters, but this is also an AWS ETL in Glue.

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv('file.csv')
    , chunksize=25000
    , on_bad_lines='skip'
    , sep=';'
    , decimal=','
    , thousands='.'
    , header=None
    , low_memory=False
    , names=fieldNames
    , dtype=dictdatatypes)):
```

I have tried removing the low_memory=False argument and there is no difference in output.  I would expect that all chunks would have all columns datatyped in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 0):

Determined that there was an obscure ; in a text field that was "pushing" string content into an otherwise numeric series. the presence of a string in the series typed the series as a string and ignored the decimal=',' argument.

Code should work once the separator is modified to use something other than a semicolon.